# How to extract messages string from JSON

Tags: ruby, json

I am attempting to reference the message array contained within this JSON but cant seem to get it.

```
[
  {
    "MessageThreadID": 1,
    "CustomerID": 171,
    "MessageType": 1,
    "Subject": "Test Message",
    "OpenDate": "2015-09-17T00:00:00",
    "Closed": false,
    "ClosedDate": null,
    "Messages": [
      {
        "IBMessageID": 1,
        "MessageThreadID": 1,
        "MessageText": "Test Message",
        "FromCustomer": true,
        "UserID": null,
        "Date": "2015-09-17T17:23:00"
      },
      {
        "IBMessageID": 2,
        "MessageThreadID": 1,
        "MessageText": "Test this Update",
        "FromCustomer": false,
        "UserID": 1,
        "Date": "2015-09-17T17:23:00"
      },
      {
        "IBMessageID": 3,
        "MessageThreadID": 1,
        "MessageText": "My New Message",
        "FromCustomer": false,
        "UserID": 1,
        "Date": "2015-09-17T17:23:00"
      },
      {
        "IBMessageID": 4,
        "MessageThreadID": 1,
        "MessageText": "Reply",
        "FromCustomer": false,
        "UserID": 1,
        "Date": "2015-09-17T17:05:00"
      },
      {
        "IBMessageID": 5,
        "MessageThreadID": 1,
        "MessageText": "Some sensible shit",
        "FromCustomer": false,
        "UserID": 1,
        "Date": "2015-09-17T17:23:00"
      },
      {
        "IBMessageID": 14,
        "MessageThreadID": 1,
        "MessageText": "Message 2",
        "FromCustomer": true,
        "UserID": null,
        "Date": "2015-09-21T14:10:00"
      },
      {
        "IBMessageID": 16,
        "MessageThreadID": 1,
        "MessageText": "Message 2",
        "FromCustomer": true,
        "UserID": null,
        "Date": "2015-09-22T16:22:00"
      },
      {
        "IBMessageID": 25,
        "MessageThreadID": 1,
        "MessageText": "Added via abacus\r\n",
        "FromCustomer": false,
        "UserID": 1,
        "Date": "2015-09-22T16:22:00"
      },
      {
        "IBMessageID": 26,
        "MessageThreadID": 1,
        "MessageText": "sdsdsdsd",
        "FromCustomer": true,
        "UserID": null,
        "Date": "2015-09-22T16:40:00"
      },
      {
        "IBMessageID": 27,
        "MessageThreadID": 1,
        "MessageText": "test",
        "FromCustomer": true,
        "UserID": null,
        "Date": "2015-09-22T17:02:00"
      },
      {
        "IBMessageID": 28,
        "MessageThreadID": 1,
        "MessageText": "test",
        "FromCustomer": true,
        "UserID": null,
        "Date": "2015-09-22T17:06:00"
      }
    ]
  }
]
```

The furthest I have gotten is:

```
@cleanmessages = JSON.parse([@messages].to_json).first
```

This returns:

```
 [  
   {  
      "IBMessageID"      =>1,
      "MessageThreadID"      =>1,
      "MessageText"      =>"Test Message",
      "FromCustomer"      =>true,
      "UserID"      =>nil,
      "Date"      =>"2015-09-17T17:23:00      "}, 
   {
      "IBMessageID"=>2,
      "MessageThreadID"      =>1,
      "MessageText"      =>"Test this Update",
      "FromCustomer"      =>false,
      "UserID"      =>1,
      "Date"      =>"2015-09-17T17:23:00      "}, 
   {
      "IBMessageID"=>3,
      "MessageThreadID"      =>1,
      "MessageText"      =>"My New Message",
      "FromCustomer"      =>false,
      "UserID"      =>1,
      "Date"      =>"2015-09-17T17:23:00      "}, 
   {
      "IBMessageID"=>4,
      "MessageThreadID"      =>1,
      "MessageText"      =>"Reply",
      "FromCustomer"      =>false,
      "UserID"      =>1,
      "Date"      =>"2015-09-17T17:05:00      "}, 
    {
      "IBMessageID"=>5,
      "MessageThreadID"      =>1,
      "MessageText"      =>"Some sensible shit",
      "FromCustomer"      =>false,
      "UserID"      =>1,
      "Date"      =>"2015-09-17T17:23:00      "}, 
   {
      "IBMessageID"=>14,
      "MessageThreadID"      =>1,
      "MessageText"      =>"Message 2",
      "FromCustomer"      =>true,
      "UserID"      =>nil,
      "Date"      =>"2015-09-21T14:10:00      "}, 
   {
      "IBMessageID"=>16,
      "MessageThreadID"      =>1,
      "MessageText"      =>"Message 2",
      "FromCustomer"      =>true,
      "UserID"      =>nil,
      "Date"      =>"2015-09-22T16:22:00      "}, 
   {
      "IBMessageID"=>25,
      "MessageThreadID"      =>1,
      "MessageText"      =>"Added via abacus\r\n",
      "FromCustomer"      =>false,
      "UserID"      =>1,
      "Date"      =>"2015-09-22T16:22:00      "}, 
   {
      "IBMessageID"=>26,
      "MessageThreadID"      =>1,
      "MessageText"      =>"sdsdsdsd",
      "FromCustomer"      =>true,
      "UserID"      =>nil,
      "Date"      =>"2015-09-22T16:40:00      "}, 
    {
      "IBMessageID"=>27,
      "MessageThreadID"      =>1,
      "MessageText"      =>"test",
      "FromCustomer"      =>true,
      "UserID"      =>nil,
      "Date"      =>"2015-09-22T17:02:00      "}, 
    {
      "IBMessageID"=>28,
      "MessageThreadID"      =>1,
      "MessageText"      =>"test",
      "FromCustomer"      =>true,
      "UserID"      =>nil,
      "Date"      =>"2015-09-22T17:06:00
   }
]
```

How do i reference each element within each array. I want to in the end be able to display each element sepearately for each thread.

Answer (score 0):

This will give you a hash with the message grouped by the `MessageThreadID`

```
@cleanmessages.group_by{ |msg_hash| msg_hash['MessageThreadID']}
```

Comment: This returns an error: "undefined method `group_by' for nil:NilClass". Apologies but how do i correctly implement this?

Answer (score 0):

Not clear what output you actually want.

```
document = JSON.parse([@messages].to_json)
document.each do |thread|
    # gives you all text messages within the current thread: "Test Message", "Test this Update", ... 
    messages = thread['Messages'].map {|m| m['MessageText']} 

    # iterates over all messages in the current thread 
    thread['Messages'].each {|m| puts "Message #{m['IBMessageID']} from thread #{thread['MessageThreadID']}"}
end
```

In general **JSON.parse** doesn't return something special. It returns either **Array** for corresponding JSON array or **Hash** for corresponding JSON object.

Comment: Where would i implement this?

Comment: Implement what? I don't know your application, how you want to store objects (data structure), and how you want to process them. And honestly it's beyond the question. You needed a piece of code to display each message from each thread. See that "puts" call? You have there a "thread" variable that is a Hash for thread properties, and "m" variable that is a Hash for a single message's properties in the given thread. And there you can do whatever you want, push in some other data structure, for instance.